# Word for attaching blame to inanimate objects

Tags: single-word-requests

In a recent court case in [Darlington](http://www.darlingtonandstocktontimes.co.uk/news/10036354.Man_attacked_ex_partner_s_door_with_machete/), a man was convicted of destroying a door with a machete. He was sentenced to some trifling inconvenience, but the magistrates were careful to order the destruction of the machete; clearly they have identified the real culprit, and have ensured no further offences will be possible.

The same thought processes were embedded in English law up to 1846 in the notion of the [deodand](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deodand), some object that caused a death and was therefore forfeit to the Crown.

The fellow who tripped over his [shoelace and destroyed some crockery](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-399456/Priceless-vase-smashed-hapless-museum-visitor-display.html) was quick to blame his shoelace; having just converted Ming vases worth £500,000 to fragments worth £diddly he was probably rather shocked and thinking in an instinctive way.

This thought process is sufficiently old and common to have a name. Does anyone know what it is? (I don't think [animism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/animism) quite covers it.)

Comment: Animism certainly doesn't cover deodand, though deodand didn't necessarily blame the object, so much as hold it to be cursed as an effect of the death, rather than the cause, and later to act as a sort of negligence fine. Animism could involve holding something actively to blame, but it's much wider than that. Not knowing of a word, I might well be tempted to stretch *deodand* into figurative service.

Comment: *Deodand* is so clearly what you need that it would be worth attempting to revive the term (C S Forester related it to the Nuremberg Trials in one of the stories in *The Nightmare*).  But the real question is; why did the door have a machete in the first place?

Comment: @TimLymington [Deodands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deodand_(fictional_creature)#Creatures_of_the_Dying_Earth) are certainly cool. *“Deodands are humanoids which look like handsome, muscular human men, but with "dead black lustreless skin and long slit eyes." They are strong, murderous, and carnivorous creatures, but can be killed with offensive spells, which they fear.”*

Comment: The phenomenon [reappears](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4064012/Greggs-fraudster-got-unlimited-food-loyalty-card-stamper.html).

Comment: The formal psychological term for this is ['ascribing agency'](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/agency/). There have been lots of experiments showing that humans and many animals will consider an object to be 'pruposeful' if it moves a certain way.

Comment: Animism?? theism, monotheism, supernaturalism,pantheism, etc.,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [pathetic fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy) is:

> the treatment of inanimate objects as if they had human feelings, thought, or sensations

Comment: +1 for the link.  I am grateful for the enlightenment.  The Tennyson poem (Crossing the Bar) made me cry.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

***"Scapegoating"*** - though usually assigned to a person, can certainly be assigned to an inanimate object.  The point is that the blame is passed onto someone/something other than the true perpetrator.

> Definition of **"scapegoat"** from [The Free Dictionary.com:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scapegoating)
>
> 1. One that is made to bear the blame of others.
> 2. Bible - A live goat over whose head Aaron confessed all the sins of the children of Israel on the Day of Atonement. The goat, symbolically bearing their sins, was then sent into the wilderness.
>
> tr.v. scape·goat·ed, scape·goat·ing, scape·goats 
>   To make a scapegoat of.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest one can get is [anthropomorphism](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anthropomorphism?q=anthropomorphism)

> the attribution of human characteristics or behaviour to a god, animal or object.

Comment: ...or personification.

Comment: I am guilty of such  ... daily!!!

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "whipping [or lashing or flogging] the Hellespont" alludes to a classic instance of the behavior described in the OP's question. The [Wikipedia entry on Xerxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerxes_I) summarizes the story:

> According to the Greek historian Herodotus, Xerxes's first attempt to bridge the Hellespont [as part of an attempted invasion of Greece] ended in failure when a storm destroyed the flax and papyrus cables of the bridges. In retaliation Xerxes ordered the Hellespont (the strait itself) whipped three hundred times and had fetters thrown into the water.

Wikipedia's Xerxes article includes an illustration (from 1909) depicting the [punishment of the waterway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerxes_I#mediaviewer/File:Xerxes_lash_sea.JPG).

Answer (score 3):

**Resistentialism**, according [to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistentialism):

> Resistentialism is a jocular theory to describe "seemingly spiteful behavior manifested by inanimate objects